# How can I vectorize this for loop below, where I need to set values to a range I need to round?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a np.array q with some values for example: [1,3,5,7] .
And a np.array z. with some values that I need to round and than they are used as index in the
Third array 'mapping'.

```
import numpy as np

    q = [1,3,5,7]
    z = [0,50.3,240.4,252.9,256]

    mapping = np.zeros(256)
    for i in range(len(q)):
        print(i)
        start, end = int(round(z[i])), int(round(z[i + 1]))
        mapping[start:end] = int(round(q[i]))

    print(mapping)
```

The output here is:
[image]

Comment: should mapping start at `0`, because *1 is between 1 and 50*?

Comment: Also why 1 only runs up to 50 but 5 runs up to 253? is it a round?

Comment: @QuangHoang you're right!, it should start from 0, you found an error in my for-loop code, even if no one will find an answer I am at least happy that you did that code review off my code. thanks. fixing my question.

Comment: Your start and end points are inconsistent at best...

Comment: Please edit the question to be consistent and make sense, and I'll be happy to provide an answer.

Comment: updated. thanks all

Comment: Your loop does not match the desired output, which does not match your prose. Please explain what you want carefully, and try to make all threetypes of  description consistent.

Comment: The loop doesn't even run :-)

Comment: fixed, and added prints, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
repeats = np.diff(list(np.round(z))+ [256]).astype(int)
# repeats = array([ 49, 191,  12,   3])

np.repeat(np.round(q), repeats)
```

Output:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7])
```

**Note**: this only has 255 elements and it's different from your expected output, because, tbh I don't really understand your logic.

Comment: wow! great solution!! thank you. so elegant. 

I did a small fix in your code, can you please update your code?

repeats = np.diff(list(np.round(z))).astype(int)
your_array = np.repeat(np.round(q), repeats)

Comment: FYI, the code is part of a program I am writing that does optimal quantization of an Image. 

the numbers are 256 colors in the origin to 4 shades of gray in the results.

I wanted to implement it myself as a training exercise.

Comment: Does that modification run?

Comment: yes, and it match exactly. marking it as 'answer' thanks

Comment: Weird, because as you posted, repeats has length 3, while q has length 4. It shouldn’t run.

Comment: the repeats is: [ 50 190  13   3]

Comment: ```import numpy as np 
    
    q = np.array([1,3,5,7])
    z = np.array([0,50.3,240.4,252.9,256])
    
    repeats = np.diff(list(np.round(z))).astype(int)
    mapping = np.repeat(np.round(q), repeats)

    print(mapping)```

Comment: I see your z is different now.